# CodeMirror determine the name of the mode

Tags: codemirror

How can I tell the name of the "mode" for each language in CodeMirror?

For example, the mode "HTML Embedded" gives this page: http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlembedded/index.html

On this page, there is a script, but it doesn't set the mode.

```
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    continueComments: "Enter",
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": "toggleComment"}
  });
```

I would expect a `mode: "somemode"` to be in this. How else can we tell the name of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first mode loaded becomes the default mode. You can do `editor.getMode().name` to get the name of the mode loaded in an editor instance.